# No known parent package

Tags: django

I made an app called calc in the project mysite. I tried this code on urls page of polls app

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlspattern = [
    path(' ',views.index, name= 'index')]
```

Then I got an ImportError

> File "c:\Users\Anmol\tomb\mysite\polls\urls.py", line 3, in
>    from . import views ImportError: attempted relative import
>   with no known parent package

Comment: show your project directory

Comment: seem like calc is a django application, try this `from calc import views`